# Where should I place iptables update on Android at boot time?

Tags: boot, bootloader, iptables

I need to write specific values in the routing system using the `iptables` command for Android.

The overall idea is that the user can navigate *only* using the provided DNS configuration.

I've tried to invoke them inside an script through the `init.rc`, but the script is never called:

```
service update_iptables /system/bin/update_iptables.sh
    start update_iptables
```

When I plug the phone to the computer and execute the following sequence, it works without problems:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell /system/bin/update_iptables.sh
```

Obviously, when restarting, this configuration is lost. That's why I need to run this as part of the start boot sequence.

Any advice on where in `init.rc` (or any other configuration file) can I place the script?

Comment: Any file that resides under **/** is reverted during boot. Your best bet would be to create a script that does your bidding, and place it under **/system/etc/init.d**. Note that the phone's kernel needs to support init.d, else this won't work.